# Bathroom venting 2 in 1

Tags: bathroom, ducts, fans

I have Installation where I will use two bath fans. One in the half bath and toilet and sink the other outside where the shower will be. I would like to combine the two into 1 the outside the house

Comment: What's the question? Furthermore, what would be the point of that arrangement?

Comment: Be careful of sound transmission. You’ll hear everything both ways.

Comment: Are you are asking how to install an exhaust fan where the motor housing is outdoors and there are two intake vents in two different rooms?  If that is the question, please Edit the question and ask it.  Or in a similar way ask an actual question that has an answer.    It's common in apartments and hotels to have a large fan on the roof that draws air from all the bathrooms in the building.  Less common in a house but it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

I grew up in a house with such a setup - bathrooms that were back to back each had a separate vent fan in the ceiling, which was combined into a single vent going out the roof.  You'll want to figure out how to put a one-way flapper on each one before they join, so that when only one is exhausting, the exhaust will go up the roof vent and not just into the other bathroom.  It worked fine for our situation, but sometimes the venting of one caused the one-way flapper of the other to rattle quite a bit, but perhaps there are better-designed one-way flappers than those built in the early 1960's.

Answer (score 0):

Bring the 2 vent pipes together into a Y-fitting just before the solitary pipe goes to the outdoors. The 2 fans enter the "top" of the Y and the exit air leaves the Y from the "bottom." With only 1 fan running, the air expands in the middle of the Y creating a venturi effect on the other leg. The airflow continues straight to the outside. It does not go around the corner and pressurize the other fan. The Y acts like an automatic one-way damper.